# Expected identifier error

Tags: ios, objective-c, identifier

So i only get one error  under the  `- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender` if someone could help this would be appreciated i have tried to only make a sound play when I press a button.

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ding" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *audioPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:nil];
    [audioPlayer play];
}

@end

@implementation SecondViewController{

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)ButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}

- (IBAction)Button {AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
}

@end
```

Comment: What's the error? (And this sure doesn't look like C++.)

Answer (score 0):

The method *definition* should not be in the `@interface` section; just the *declaration*:

```
@interface SecondViewController ()

- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender;

@end
```

Then move the definition into the `@implementation` section with the following change:

You are using the identifier (variable name) `audioPath` twice for different objects.  Change the second to `audioURL` or somesuch:

```
- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ding" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];   // HERE
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:nil];
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing - (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {} in the Header file(.h)???

You can declare your playAudio IBAction in your .h, but implement it in your .m

Your files should look like this:

```
@interface SecondViewController ()

- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation SecondViewController{

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)ButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}

- (IBAction)Button {AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ding" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *audioPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:nil];
    [audioPlayer play];
}

@end
```